# Show side pane after search and find?

Tags: evince

I had side pane showing "index" on the left part of Evince Window. Then I did search and find, which took over the place of side pane. After that, I would like to see side pane again, but can't find a way. I wonder  how? Thanks. Evince 3.10.3 in Ubuntu 14.04.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Pressing <kbd>F9</kbd> in a pdf will open up the side panel and pressing it again will hide it.

Your selection will be remembered.

Comment: You might need to combine this with the answer of Thiago: click on the magnifying class to remove the search result window, which hides the content.

Comment: I had to close and open the app for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to click on magnifying glass button (at top left corner of window) second time. It will restore your topics sidebar.

Comment: You might need to combine this with the answer of  24601: Press F9 to toggle on the content window.

Answer (score 0):

Check the box Side Pane in the View Options like in the image:

[image: evince Side Pane setting image]